# Logging into https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Maybe I am making this more complicated then I need to.  I am learning about Phantom JS I figured I could use that to automate Android App submissions to the Amazon App Store/Amazon Developer Console.  The login page has this URL: http://developer.amazon.com/home.html

It redirects to a super long URL and presents a form to enter one's username and password and a button to click.  If you look at page source you see a form that has all sorts of hidden inputs.  Here is the part of the actual form tag from the page source:

```
<form name="signIn" method="POST" id="ap_signin_form" novalidate="novalidate" action="https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin" onsubmit="var test1 = apCheckRequiredFields('ap_signin_form', ['ap_email','ap_password']);
        return (apValidateEmail('ap_email') &amp;&amp; test1);">
      <input type="hidden" name="appActionToken" value="scIhj2FOCtxr39z7eUIj2FWeNOWxtIwj3D"><input type="hidden" name="appAction" value="SIGNIN">
                <input type="hidden" name="openid.pape.max_auth_age" value="ape:MQ==">
                <input type="hidden" name="openid.return_to" value="ape:aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXZlbG9wZXIuYW1hem9uLmNvbS9hcF9sb2dpbi82ODc0NzQ3MDczM0EyRjJGNjQ2NTc2NjU2QzZGNzA2NTcyMkU2MTZENjE3QTZGNkUyRTYzNkY2RDJGNjg2RjZENjUyRTY4NzQ2RDZDLmh0bWw=">
                <input type="hidden" name="prevRID" value="ape:N1RBVEM3SFQxSEdXRTNITUFENEs=">
                <input type="hidden" name="openid.identity" value="ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjAvaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Q=">
                <input type="hidden" name="openid.assoc_handle" value="ape:bWFzX2Rldl9wb3J0YWw=">
                <input type="hidden" name="openid.mode" value="ape:Y2hlY2tpZF9zZXR1cA==">
                <input type="hidden" name="language" value="ape:ZW5fVVM=">
                <input type="hidden" name="openid.claimed_id" value="ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjAvaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Q=">
                <input type="hidden" name="pageId" value="ape:bWFzX2Rldl9wb3J0YWwy">
                <input type="hidden" name="openid.ns" value="ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjA=">
  <div id="ap_signin1a_pagelet" class="ap_table ap_pagelet">
    <div id="ap_signin1a_pagelet_title" class="ap_row ap_pagelet_title">
      <h1>Sign In </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="ap_signin1a_email_section_title" class="ap_row ap_section_title">
      <h2>
            What is your email (phone for mobile accounts)?

... even more html here ...
```

I am kind of confused about what I am suppose to do with the Phantom JS code. Do I need to collect all these hidden inputs and build a form data object to send in a POST request?  Or do I just need to figure out what DOM objects I need to set to my my credentials and then generate a button click event?

Comment: `figure out what DOM objects I need to set to my my credentials and then generate a button click event` exactly

Comment: Thanks Vaviloff. I'll give that a shot.